# I cant set 'eval.points' in kcde (or similar) from ks package

Tags: r

I'm trying to estimate the bivariate distribution of some data with the function kcda from package 'ks'.

The problem is that I want to give the 'eval.points' parameter of the function but I had the error:

```
`> F  <- kcde(x=x,H,eval.points=C$eval.points)
 Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'`
```

C is another estimation and I want to estimate at the same points.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Best regards,

Sergio

Comment: It probably a mismatch between tyring to send a dataframe to an argument that expects a vector. You need at the very minimum tell us _exactly_ what all of those datatypes are (in proper R parlance). If you want to keep this from being "twenty questions" then you need to give us an actual data object. Learn to use `dput`.